# Discord.py - Bot vs Client

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make this simple bot with some functions.
Currently, I am stuck on this problem. I want to welcome new members and have a command for changing nicknames on the server. Usually, I try every function standalone, and they work on their own. Whenever I try to combine them into one big functional bot, I run into trouble.

I am using `Bot` and `Client` at the same time, which probably causes problems. Unfortunately, I don't know how to rewrite the bot command into client command and vice versa. This is the code I'm working with:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("member join")
    channel = client.get_channel(929370329363644506)
    #embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome!",description=f"{member.mention} Just Joined")
    await channel.send(f"{member.mention} Welcome to our server! Please check <#556206910794366988> and set your name and rank based on your ingame name and rank")

bot = Bot("!")
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(change_nickname=True)
async def nick(ctx, *, nickname):
    member = ctx.author
    await member.edit(nick=nickname)
    await ctx.send(f"Nickname was changed to {member.mention}.")


my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
bot.run(my_secret)
```

With that, welcoming the members doesn't work; changing nick is fine.
The first thing I tried was to change the `@client.event` to `@bot.event` and define `bot` as `bot = discord.Client()` but that didn't help.

I would prefer to write the whole bot with `@bot`.
I am guessing I'm missing the fundamentals a bit, but if there is someone who can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate that.

Comment: commands.Bot has all the functionality that discord.Client offers, including events.

Comment: ``bot = discord.Client`` and just make everything @bot.command. Both offer the same functions.

Comment: well because you haven’t enabled intents for the bot, only for the client.

Comment: hello @Willwell, thank you! so i went and redecorate the code like this:

bot = discord.Client
#bot.command
async def on_member_join(member):
        fnc..
#bot.command
async def on_message(message):
        fnc..

but after that I get "AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command' " this error. Do you have any idea how to fix that please? Or did I redecorate the code wrongly? Thanks ! (the # instead of @ is cuz stack wouldnt let me post it due to tagging too many members)

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński can you be more specific please? If I just rewrote client event to bot event, in the two rows above I define intents for the whole bot ? Maybe if you would be so kind to post the edited code? I have trouble following it, sorry

Comment: You have only *defined* intents, you haven’t passed them to the bot constructor — `bot = Bot("!", intents=intents)`

Comment: Thank you man, I knew I am missing something basic! It is working now thanks again. I upovted ur comment, not sure If I can mark it as the answer, if you want make a extra reply and I will mark it as a solver

Comment: @KDK Intents hasn't been passed to the bot. ``intents=intents``

Answer (score 1):

You never run the `client`. Since the `client` and `bot` are different variables you need to run them both seperately. So, just add `client.run(my_secret)` to your code.

---

P.S. I highly recommend you to use only Bot as it has all the functionality of a discord client but also supports commands, command groups, cogs, etc. Also as Lukasz said you never add your intents (and while it won't throw any error if you don't define them it's generally better practice to do so).

Comment: Why do you write PS in a typed answer?

Comment: it's just something i wanted to mention other than what was asked in the question so i mentioned it as a post script

Comment: Thanks for the explanation man makes sense now. Yep I re-did the code and everything is Bot now, it also made more sense to me do it like that.